# Access variables created in a method of another class

Tags: python, class, variables, pyqt5, signals-slots

I would like to recall a variable of another class without having to make it global. I can not make it! Will you help me?

```
class labTreeMap(QLabel):
    clickedQL = pyqtSignal()
    def mouseReleaseEvent(self,event):
        if event.button() == Qt.LeftButton:
            xTM = event.pos().x()
            yTM = event.pos().y()
            self.clickedQL.emit()

class TreeMap(QWidget):
    def click_TreeMap(self,c):
        xTM=labTreeMap.mouseReleaseEvent.xTM  # recall xTM from here
        yTM=labTreeMap.mouseReleaseEvent.yTM  # recall yTM from here
```

Comment: 1. Note about terminology: We "access" variables but don't "call" them. 2. I encourage you to learn about Object Oriented Programming principles. In particular, "encapsulation" applies here. In short, this principle encourages us to access a class's behavior through its methods and not access variables directly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The idiomatic way to do this in PyQt is to emit the values as signal parameters so they are directly available as arguments within any connected slot:

```
class LabTreeMap(QLabel):
    clickedQL = pyqtSignal(int, int) # declare paramter types

    def mouseReleaseEvent(self,event):
        if event.button() == Qt.LeftButton:
            xTM = event.pos().x()
            yTM = event.pos().y()
            self.clickedQL.emit(xTM, yTM) # emit paramters

class TreeMap(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        ...
        self.treeMapChart = TreeMapChart()
        ...
        self.labTreeMap = LabTreeMap()
        self.labTreeMap.clickedQL.connect(self.click_TreeMap)

    def click_TreeMap(self, xTM, yTM):
        # do something with parameters
        print(f'{xTM=}, {yTM=}')
        # do something with chart
        print(self.treeMapChart)
```

Comment: Forgive me ekhumoro, I changed two statements to:
self.labTreeMap.clickedQL.connect(lambda: self.click_TreeMap(c,xTM,yTM))
….
def click_TreeMap(self,c,xTM,yTM):
….
But it says ‘xTM and yTM‘ are not defined

Comment: @Nepura What is the `c` argument? Where does the value of that argument come from?

Comment: It is an TreeMapChart object created some line before and that I need in the click_TreeMap() function

Comment: @Nepura See my updated my answer. You don't need that `c` argument or the `lambda`.

Answer (score 1):

Make them instance variables.

```
class labTreeMap(QLabel):
    clickedQL = pyqtSignal()
    def mouseReleaseEvent(self,event):
        if event.button() == Qt.LeftButton:
            self.xTM = event.pos().x()
            self.yTM = event.pos().y()
            self.clickedQL.emit()

class TreeMap(QWidget):
    def click_TreeMap(self,c):
        xTM=someLabTreeMap.xTM  # recall xTM from here
        yTM=someLabTreeMap.yTM  # recall yTM from here
```

Replace `someLabTreeMap` with the variable that holds the `labTreeMap` object that `mouseReleaseEvent()` was called on earlier.

Comment: Err... surely `labTreeMap.xTM` is an `AttributeError`?

Comment: Right, that should be a variable that holds an instance.

Comment: Yes, it gives me this error: 'labTreeMap' has no attribute 'xTM'

Answer (score 0):

Ideally you need to make `TreeMap` rely on an instance of `labTreeMap` given to it when it is instantiated.

The following is a poor copy of your classes, but shows how `TreeMap` gets and instance of `labTreeMap`:

```py
class labTreeMap:
    def foo(self):
        self.xTM = 0

class TreeMap:
    def __init__(self, ltm):
        self.ltm = ltm
    def click_TreeMap(self,c):
        xTM=self.ltm.xTM  # recall xTM from here

l = labTreeMap()
l.foo()   # create the xTM attribute
t = TreeMap(l)
t.click_TreeMap(0)
```